# Как удалить репозиторий в новой версии Bitbucket?

Tags: git, bitbucket, repository

Подскажите, как удалить репозиторий ? Со сменой дизайна не могу найти кнопки, которая это делает bitbucket.org

[image: bitbucket.org Settings]
[image: bitbucket.org Settings2]

Куда засунули функционал ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

На странице `/admin` в правом верхнем углу есть меню (три точки). И там «*Delete repository*».

Comment: Что-то не наблюдаться.... можно картинку прикрепить ?

Comment: @BlackStar1991 https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rvm25.png